# SQL Pivoting a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

suppose I have a temp table created and the structure/data looks like this

```
  Type        Lang    N_cnt        Pcnt      T1      T2       T3      T4
============================================================================
ClassroomA      1      165897      1232     6439    1135     4516     1756
ClassroomA      2      175127      1254     6439    1135     1285     1953
ClassroomB      1      179515      1284     6439    1762     3945     1957
ClassroomB      2      159683      2041     6439    1575     4745     1955
```

I wanna pivot the `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, `T4` columns such that I get this result

```
   Type       SubType   Lang      N_cnt            P_cnt   
==============================================================
ClassroomA      NULL     1       165897          1232  
NULL            "T1"     1   6439/165897     6439/1232       
NULL            "T2"     1       *calculation*   *calculation*
NULL            "T3"     1       *calculation*   *calculation*
NULL            "T4"     1       *calculation*   *calculation*
ClassroomA      NULL     2       175127          1254  
NULL            "T1"     2       6439/175127     6439/1254       
NULL            "T2"     2       *calculation*   *calculation*
NULL            "T3"     2       *calculation*   *calculation*
NULL            "T4"     2       *calculation*   *calculation*
```

Note that where it says `calculation` thats where I will be taking the value of `T{x}` and doing some calucation with it (I do an example for the first `T1`). I would also like to add that in reality I have about ten over these `T` variables.

Any ideas how to pivot the columns?

Answer (score 3):

You can use something similar to this:

```
select type, 
  case when subtype = 'start' then null else subtype end subtype,
  lang, 
  case when subtype = 'start' then n_cnt else value/(n_cnt * 1.0) end n_cnt,
  case when subtype = 'start' then pcnt else value/(pcnt * 1.0) end pcnt
from
(
  select type, lang, n_cnt, pcnt, 
    T1, T2, T3, T4, 0 as start
  from table1
) x
unpivot 
(
  value 
  for subtype in (T1, T2, T3, T4, start)
) un
order by type, lang, subtype;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d16a1/43)

Comment: Awsome thanks, however my table structure is a bit more complicated then the example i gave and I dont really understand the query. However I am working on modifying it to make it work for me. I will mark it as correct answer in a bit THanks :)

Comment: Lets say I want two sets of pivot. it, I have the T columns and also P columns, and I want to display them side by side. I've edited the schema to include those columns in the link you sent
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62862/2/0 but I don't know how to edit the code

Comment: Checking for `value = 0` in the second and third CASEs may be unreliable. What if any one of `T1`, `T2` etc. turns out to be `0`? I think it would be safer to use the same condition as in the first CASE (`subtype = 'start'`). Other than that, I really like this approach!

Comment: @masfenix you would just add the fields to the `unpivot` portion of the query -- see this fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62862/13